# How to delete directory trees safely

Tags: python, directory

I want my python program to delete directory trees which were created by the program during a previous execution. I worry that if there is a bug in the program using `shutil.rmtree` migth delete much more then intended with catastrophic consequences. Are there any best practises on how to avoid that?

I had the following ideas but they dont seem very elegant to me:

- Exactly determine every file created by the program and delete them one-by-one and delete empty directories afterwards.
- Determining the size or number of files of a directory and putting an upper bound on them. (E.g. only delete folders with size less than 5MB and less then 100 files.)

Comment: If your program is creating temporary files/directories which you have to delete afterwards why not create them using [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html)?

Comment: @VladSiv The files are the results of the program and I only want to delete them if a new run would produce new results.

Comment: Could your program then overwrite the old output? That would solve the issue with deleting.

Comment: @VladSiv The tree of result files might change depending on the input which means some outdated files might not be overwritten if I do not delete them somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue here:

- a third party is writing files in folders I have to provide
- it fails if the folders are not empty
- there are "re-runs": I am likely to provide again the same folder

Some modest trick ideas I'm using:

1. there is one and only one method in the whole codebase that performs `shutil.rmtree` and it has some basic safety checks:

   1. check the depth against a safety value `if len(pathlib.Path(dir_to_delete).parents) < SAFETY_RMTREE_DEPTH:`
   2. add an optional prompt boolean that issues a blocking prompt before delete, with default to True (or anything similar that blocks execution as GUI prompts might not always be available): `def delete_folder(folder: Path, prompt: bool = True)`. If you forget to set the prompt to False, then it forces you to think again about it the first time it gets executed.
      Might not work if the first ever execution happens in production...
   3. upper bounds on file size or number would be OK as you suggested if the checks are not too costly
2. Each time I am about to use the main `delete_folder` I try to instead define a specific delete method `def delete_xxx` that first checks that the target looks like what I want to delete. Specific checks could be tags or extensions in filenames, etc.
3. In some cases it is possible to move to a garbage instead of deleting
4. It might be OK to always add a timestamp to a specific folder you need to provide to the third party. Many issues can come from timestamping but for simple applications that might be acceptable.

Also, an online search with "criteria-based deletion" seems to give some results with similar tricks.